# Display MysQl rows lesser than or equal to 15 mins ago Timestamp

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have simple script that query the database every 30 sec to get latest notification with setInterval(). How can I display only rows that are lesser than or equal to 15 mins ago? I don't want to show anything greater than 15 mins. Right now I'm using something that is lesser than 24 hours which is good but not precise enough.

**Curent Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM notifications n 
JOIN employees e ON n.fromEmployee_id=e.employee_id 
WHERE n.lastUpdate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
ORDER BY n.id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the interval:

```
SELECT *
FROM notifications n JOIN
     employees e
     ON n.fromEmployee_id = e.employee_id 
WHERE n.lastUpdate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 minute) 
ORDER BY n.id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

You may not want the `LIMIT 1` if you want all the rows.

Comment: Ok . I didn`t know it was as simple as that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way would be to compare your timestamp (and only timestamp, without using any functions on it) to an expression that can be calculated as constant for every row, this way mysql can use index defined on your timestamp column.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE lastupdated >= NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE
```